# How does it make sense to just put the integral sign in front of each side of an equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

My textbook says that you can solve first-order differential equations in the form

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = f(x)g(y) $$

by writing

$$ \int{\frac1{g(y)}}dy = \int{f(x)} dx $$

the explanation is not provided, but I feel like it's heavily implying that they're cross multiplying the $dx$ and dividing each side by $g(y)$.

$$ \frac1{g(y)}dy = f(x)dx $$

But then we should add an integral sign in the front?

$$ \int{\frac1{g(y)}}dy = \int{f(x)} dx $$

I don't know if this is the case, but incase it is, why does this make sense and can we add an integral sign to any equation with a $dx$ or $dy$ on either sides?

Comment: There are surely better answers than this, but here's an answer I think has value nonetheless: You can always check a proposed solution to a differential equation ... so if a method gives you a solution that you can check is correct, in a sense that's all that matters!

Comment: In your example, is $y$ supposed to be defined as $y=f(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x)g(y),$ divide by $g(y)$. Then we are left with
$$
\frac{1}{g(y(x))} \frac{dy}{dx}=f(x).
$$
Since this holds for all $x$, the left and the right must have the same antiderivative. Hence,
$$
\int \frac{1}{g(y(x))} \frac{dy}{dx} dx + C_1=\int f(x) + C_2.
$$
But note that $dy=\frac{dy}{dx} dx$ so the left hand side becomes
$$
\int \frac{1}{g(y)}dy + C_1.
$$
We can bring the constants to one side (either as $C_1-C_2$ or $C_2-C_1$), and since they are both arbitrary, we can represent this as an arbitrary constant $C$.

Comment: Instead of formal calculations with $dx, dy$ terms you can simply apply the substitution rule: $\int_a^b \frac{1}{g(y(x))} y'(x) dx = \int_{y(a)}^{y(b)} \frac{1}{g(y)} dy$.